# How to study the ODE $x'(t) = \sqrt{x(t)^2 + 1}$ with $x(0)=a$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following ODE :

$x'(t) = \sqrt{x(t)^2+1}$, $x(0) = a \in \mathbb{R}$.

We have to determine if the Cauchy-Lipschitz's theorem is verified, and determinate if the maximal solution is global (defined on $\mathbb{R}$).

For me, $\sqrt{x(t)^2+1}$ is of class $C^1$, then we can apply the CL theorem. But as the ODE hasn't constant solutions, how to study the problem ? Thank you in advance...

Comment: I think we don't have the right to directly calculate the explicit solution, we have to "study" the problem :(

Comment: @MélanieDelaCheminée: You _always_ have the right to solve an ODE, even if your ultimate analysis does not explicitly rely on the (secret) knowledge and inspiration you find. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get estimates on the growth of the solutions.

Solutions are increasing, and $x'\ge1$. This implies that $x(t)\ge a+t$ for all $t$ in the interval of existence. We can then asume without loss of generality that $x(t)\ge0$. Then we have $x'(t)\le x(t)+1$, and from here you can deduce that solutions are global.